# Free software to design magazine covers and pages

Tags: windows, gratis, graphic-design, desktop-publishing

Am looking for free software to design magazine covers and pages (magazine pages with rich color and images). I searched web and found this - https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/3144/software-recommendations-for-magazine-layout . But I can't handle such great software packages and they are not free either.

So suggest me a free tool with maximum functionality to design magazine covers and pages. It should run on any version of Windows including server versions, should be easy to use and should have a nice UI.

Comment: "need to have as many as features possible" is a bit vague (and might tempt people to vote your question closed for being "too broad"). What are your must-have features? On what OS must it be able to run – or would you also consider web-apps?

Comment: Adding a bounty is good, but answering questions from @Izzy would get you even better attention...

Comment: Have you looked at Scribus? Does it have what you want, and if not what is missing?

Comment: @holroy No. It is not up to my expectations.

Comment: How is it not up to your expectations? You're asking for recommendations but don't specify/clarify what you need. How are we supposed to help you then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serif has a Free Desktop Publishing application called [PagePlus](http://www.serif.com/desktop-publishing-software/).
[image]

- Stunning stationery is so simple
- Easy drag and drop designing
- Layouts in a couple of clicks
- Precise and easy design tools
- Versatile desktop publishing
- Help is always on hand
- Simple to use and great support
- Clean UI
- Runs on any version of Windows

Comment: That's only the "starter edition" for free. What limitations does it have compared to the full version?

Comment: @vclaw This chart compares PagePlus Starter Edition to the PagePlus Full Version, http://www.serif.com/pageplus/starteredition/whyupgrade/

Answer (score 8):

the one software that comes in my mind is [Scribus](http://www.scribus.net/):

- cross platform
- F(L)OSS software
- supports RGB, CMYK and spot colors
- shipped with almost 200 color palettes, and almost 400 more for download in the next stable version
- PDF/X-3 specification