# Is there a software with the purpose to create scientific posters?

Tags: pdf, graphic-design, visual-design

A scientific poster is usually printed on a huge paper format (A0 or A1) containing text but mainly figures that should present a scientific topic in a consolidated yet interesting and self-explaining way.

Several software packages *can* be used to produce a poster. The ones I have some experience with are Adobe Illustrator, Photoshop and Latex (beamer and tikz packages - [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341/how-to-create-posters-using-latex) is a good starting point if you want to write a poster with latex). And I usually end up using Latex, thinking that there should be an easier way to create a scientific poster.

So, I'm wondering, is there a software that *just* does posters? Or what is the best option (software wise) to produce a scientific poster?

Comment: See related question [Free software to design magazine covers and pages](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/20949/free-software-to-design-magazine-covers-and-pages) here on Software Recommendations, or [What software can be used to create scientific posters?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/31435) on Graphic Design.

Comment: Some ideas/links: [What features does Adobe Illustrator lack compared to Microsoft PowerPoint for making posters?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/49661/452)

Comment: What is your platform/OS? Actually, [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/) could do this quite well, I think. I've used it to create roller-banner PDFs (80x200cm).

Comment: @Dɑvïd: I second this suggestion, and I have indeed done several scientific posters (in computer science) using Inkscape. Would you like to write an answer and capture the rep?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper dito. Also ended up using Inkscape.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [LibreOffice Impress](https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/impress/) as well as regular Powerpoint, where we've made stick templates of the appropriate size and orientation for students to put content into. This then gets output as PDF for the printers. Preparing the generic PPT is an effort but the consistency of output is well worth it.